# How to change checkbox size in GEF (org.eclipse.draw2d.Checkbox)

Tags: java, draw2d

In GEF (Graphical Editing Framework), is it possible to change the size of a check box and the check mark inside it?

I tried three methods:

- setPreferredSize
- setSize
- setBounds

But they can only widen the padding between it and its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checkbox` is implemented by using an Image inside a label. There are two images, one for the checked checkbox and one for the unchecked checkbox. Because of this, I don't there is an easy way to re-size the checkbox.

Possible solutions:
  1. If you just need a larger checkbox of a specific size, create your own `Checkbox`. The code of the original class is small and very simple.
  2. If you need the checkbox's size to change, you will have to create a new `Graphics` object and create a new image on demand using the `scale` method (this is a bit complex, you have to create a `GC` from a new image, create an `SWTGraphics` using the GC and then scale it.
  3. Convince your client that he doesn't want a new checkbox :-).

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am thinking about. At first, I will try to persuade the customers to change their mind, and if they don't, I will need to create a custom check box.